# iphone:UIWebview gradient background with CSS possible?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to give gradient to UIwebview's background which I load as:

```
    [self.webView  loadHTMLString:customHtml baseURL:nil];
```

but this html line does not give the effect, anyone knows how to do this better or can fix this css?

```
    [customHtml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", @" <body style='background-color:#4b95bf; webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#55aaee), to(#003366));'>"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS is incorrect `webkit-gradient()` is not a property, rather it `-webkit-gradient()` is a value.

Rather the HTML should contain:

```
[customHtml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", @" <body style='background-color:#4b95bf; background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#55aaee), to(#003366));'>"]];
```

Note the `-` before the `webkit-gradient` and the `background-image:`

Comment: tnx now but I have another problem, gradient only applies to visible area, when I scroll the webview gradient starts again, any idea?

Comment: pls look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526176/iphoneuiwebview-gradient-back-ground-starts-over-when-scrolling-down-the-content