# iPhone:UIWebview Gradient background starts-over when scrolling down the content

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios

When I apply the gradient background to uiwebview custom html content it only applies to visible area , when scroll down the content the gradient starts again from top color value again, any ideas?

```
[customHtml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", @" <body style='background-color:#4b95bf; background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#55aaee), to(#003366));'>"]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 background-attachment:fixed;
```